# How to make shared libraries with Bazel at Tensorflow

Tags: shared-libraries, tensorflow, bazel

I've tried building [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) with [bazel](http://www.bazel.io/) as follows:

> bazel build -c opt --copt="-fPIC" --copt="-g0"
>   //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package

I couldn't see `.so` file under `~/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/core`.

There are no `.so` files but `.lo` files and `.a` files.

Could you tell me how to make `.so` files of tensorflow library?

Answer (score 8):

`//tensorflow:libtensorflow.so` is the target you are looking for.

```
bazel build -c opt //tensorflow:libtensorflow.so
```

should produce the file in `bazel-bin/tensorflow`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I can make the shared library. I could use it with Rcpp.

Comment: Unexpected error reading .blazerc file '/Users/HaraHara/Downloads/tensorflow-master/.tf_configure.bazelrc'