# How to use TensorFlow C++ api as a shared library with bazel?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, bazel

Now I can build TensorFlow C++ api as a shared library refer to [make shared libraries with Bazel at Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38256180/how-to-make-shared-libraries-with-bazel-at-tensorflow), `libtensorflow_cc.so` and `libtensorflow_framework.so` file can be locate at `bazel-bin/tensorflow`.

I am not familiar with bazel, how should I use those TF shared library with bazel to write C++ code, could you please provide an example like that [links](https://github.com/rockzhuang/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/cc/dataset/tfrecord_test.cc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bazel](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/4.2.2/guide.html) is just a tool like make or cmake. For compiling your code using bazel, you have to create a build file `BUILD`. Suppose that your code is at, e.g., `tensorflow/tensorflow/test/code.cpp`:

```
#include "tensorflow/core/public/session.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/platform/env.h"

using namespace tensorflow;

...
```

create a `BUILD` file (in the same folder) containing contents like this:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "code",
    srcs = ["code.cc"],
    deps = [
        "//tensorflow/core:tensorflow",
    ]
)
```

then configure and compile your code using command:

```
cd tensorflow
./configure
cd tensorflow/tensorflow/test
bazel build :code
```

An executable will be available at `bazel-bin` folder in tensorflow root directory.

---

However, the compiled code can be huge (> 100 MB) so it is better to link your code to TensorFlow's shared libraries. Both `libtensorflow_cc.so` and `libtensorflow_framework.so` can be used in your codes like other shared library files (`.so`). The following is a common way to do so.

1. Compile the C++ code using the header library file (`.h`) using the shared library (`libtensorflow_cc.so` or/and `libtensorflow_framework.so`), e.g.,

   ```
   g++ -fPIG -Wall -o code code.cpp -L/usr/lib/libtensorflow_cc.so -ltensorflow_cc
   ```
2. Set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the location of `.so` files
3. Use `ldd your_code.out` to confirm if your executable is properly linked to a shared library.
4. Run the executable (e.g. `./your_code.out`)